# Materail ui Icon load make big Cumulative Layout Shift

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, material-ui, icons

I have the following website that is using React, Nextjs and Material ui

https://generator-rentals.co.il/

when the page load I get big Cumulative Layout Shift that is caused by an svg material ui Icon that load big and then get to the styled height and width.

How this size change of the icon that cause huge Cumulative Layout Shift can be fixed?

As seen in the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experience, I am not sure what I did that helped but it seems it is gone, I changed all icons import from

```
import {WebAssetOff as WebAssetOffIcon} from "@mui/icons-material";
```

to

```
import WebAssetOffIcon from "@mui/icons-material/WebAssetOff";
```

Before:

```
<WebAssetOffIcon sx={{maxWidth: 60, maxHeight: 60 }} />
```

After:

```
<WebAssetOffIcon style={{ maxWidth: 60, maxHeight: 60 }} />
```

Someone mentioned:
"The cause is the fact that the icon is being rendered before the CSS is loaded."